# Como controlar tipo de arquivo em Javascript sem capturar extensão?

Tags: javascript

Exemplo:

```
<input type="file" name="meu arquivo">
```

Sei que existe o método de capturar o nome da extensão descrita, mas meu objetivo é evitar que o cliente troque a extensão do arquivo, por exemplo, `PDF` para `TXT` e tente submeter o arquivo.Quero que ele carregue arquivos .ret, .data, .txt e outros.Alguém sabe se é possível tal loucura?

Comment: Isso seria possível verificando o *MIME type* do arquivo, mas até onde eu sei o JavaScript não consegue pegar o *MIME type*, você teria que verificar com uma linguagem *server-side*.

Comment: @Kazzkiq, sei que o php faz isso, mas o problema é que não gostaria de enviar para o servidor.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode recuperar o MIME Type da seguinte forma:

```
var mimeType = document.getElementById('fileUploader').files[0].type;
if (mimeType == "text/plain") { ... }
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/vrcca/Ld8kc/

Se você quiser saber se o MIME Type é um txt, zip, etc, você pode utilizar o [FileTypes.JS](https://github.com/vrcca/filetypes.js).

```
var mimeType = document.getElementById('fileUploader').files[0].type
if (Stretchr.Filetypes.extensionFor(mimeType) == "txt") { ... }
```

Comment: No caso para saber o MIME então tenho que usar FileType.JS não há outra maneira?

Comment: Não, o FileType.JS é só pro caso de você querer lidar com "js" ao invés de "application/javascript". Vou adicionar exemplos na resposta.

Comment: Adicionei os exemplos. Por enquanto o FileType.JS não tem a função extensionFor(texto), mas eu criei um fork do repositório deles e adicionei essa função: https://github.com/vrcca/filetypes.js. Estou aguardando a aceitação do pessoal do FileTypes das minhas mudanças: https://github.com/stretchr/filetypes.js/pull/2.

Comment: Segundo a outra resposta "A maior parte das soluções de detecção de MIME Type atuais se baseiam na extensão do arquivo - O FileType.JS, por exemplo, faz exatamente isso." então @RogersCorrêa acaba tendo o mesmo problema que está tentando evitar

Comment: Realmente, acabei de testar e verifiquei que o .type é definido pela extensão do arquivo.. :(

Comment: fiz um teste com um arquivo .sql e o retorno foi nada

Comment: Aqui retornou application/sql

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: Não há como no momento.

**Resposta longa**: Sim, é possível, mas não com as ferramentas atuais.

A maior parte das soluções de detecção de `MIME Type` atuais se baseiam na extensão do arquivo - O FileType.JS, por exemplo, faz exatamente isso.

Para determinar o `content-type` correto, você precisa abrir o arquivo e investigar por headers de formatos conhecidos, também conhecidos como *Magic Bytes* (ou *Magic Numbers*).

Alguns exemplos ([fonte](https://www.netspi.com/blog/entryid/185/magic-bytes-identifying-common-file-formats-at-a-glance)):

```
Executáveis                 Mnemônico       Assinatura (bytes)
DOS Executable              "MZ"            0x4D 0x5A
PE32 Executable             "MZ"...."PE.."  0x4D 0x5A ... 0x50 0x45 0x00 0x00
Mach-O Executable (32 bit)  "FEEDFACE"      0xFE 0xED 0xFA 0xCE
Mach-O Executable (64 bit)  "FEEDFACF"      0xFE 0xED 0xFA 0xCF
ELF Executable              ".ELF"          0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46

Protocolos de compressão    Mnemônico       Assinatura (bytes)
Zip Archives                "PK.."          0x50 0x4B 0x03 0x04
Rar Archives                "Rar!...."      0x52 0x61 0x72 0x21 0x1A 0x07 0x01 0x00
Ogg Container               "OggS"          0x4F 0x67 0x67 0x53
Matroska/EBML Container     N/A             0x45 0x1A 0xA3 0xDF

Image File Formats          Mnemônico       Assinatura (bytes)
PNG Image                   ".PNG...."      0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47 0x0D 0x0A 0x1A 0x0A
BMP Image                   "BM"            0x42 0x4D
GIF Image                   "GIF87a"        0x47 0x49 0x46 0x38 0x37 0x61
GIF Image                   "GIF89a"        0x47 0x49 0x46 0x38 0x39 0x61
```

([Mais informações via Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)))

Uma das novas possibilidades oferecidas pela especificação HTML5 é a *File API*, sendo possível abrir arquivos e realizar look-ups pelos tais magic bytes. Ainda assim você encontrará alguns problemas:

- Alguns formatos não possuem magic bytes, sendo impossível distinguir seu conteúdo sem algum tipo de *parsing*: por exemplo, arquivos JavaScript versus HTML versus arquivos de texto puro.
- Alguns formatos possuem magic bytes repetidos.